# Re-arrangement of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we define a series as $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} s_k$, then a series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} t_k$ is a re-arrangement of $s_k$. If there is a one-to-one association like a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $t_{f(k)} = s_k, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.

This definition doesn't really make sense to me.

Would anyone mind showing me an example of a series and it's re-arrangement, and how it verifies the definition?

For instance, given the alternating harmonic series:

$$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots \tag{1}$$

Why is $(2)$ considered a re-arrangement

$$1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots \tag{2}$$

but $(3)$ isn't

$$1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6}+ \ \cdots \tag{3}$$

considered a re-arrangement?

Comment: It's really not clear what the series in your example are, so it's hard to say anything about it, but you can only rearrange convergent series.

Comment: @Henrik Sorry, let me edit my post. The first one as you can see is a re-arrangement of the alternating harmonic series.

Comment: It is not a rearrangement, because you are not only changing the order but also the sign of some elements and as a result you are adding different numbers. 
@Henrik In order to rearrange the order of summing without changing the result, the series must absolutely convergent. Convergence is not enough.

Comment: Ah yes, I did notice the sign change. But there is another example given, which doesn't have a sign change.

$1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} ...$

I now that the $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{6}$ don't appear in the example, but can you reasonably assume that they won't at some stage in that example?

Comment: $1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9} ... $ is not a definition of a series. You cannot say anything about it if you don't know all the elements you're summing and their order. It's like asking is this series convergent: $1+2+\frac{1}{5}+3+...$ ?

Comment: A rearranged series has the same exact terms as the original series - no duplications, no omissions, no sign changes - only in a different order. The only way the series example in your comment Enigmatic (which you haven't defined) could be a rearrangement of the original is if $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{6}$ *do* appear in the series farther down the line, along with every other term in the original series. This makes perfect sense if you know what the word "rearrange" means.

Comment: @rafalpw: Of course.

Comment: Thanks @whacka and other commentors. The two examples were from the textbook, and now I understand why I was confused.